# File download dialog for photos hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

My web application will host full size photos on Amazon S3 and we use S3 as our media server. We also allow the users to download the full-size photos. Our web server is on a different hosting company. On our web application, how can we force a File Download dialog box instead of showing the photo in browser directly from an Amazon S3 URL? For example, the image url could be "http://my.s3.amazonaws.com/12345.jpg"

One solution would be to download the image to our web server which is running Django, and then force a file download dialog, but will cost double bandwidth and double the download time as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you can get S3 to specify the content type of the files as application/octet-stream.

I have just verified this.  In the AWS management console you can select a file, click on Properties, select the Metadata tab and then set the Content-Type to "binary/octet-stream".  If it's e.g. image/jpeg it will display in the browser.  If it's changed to binary/octet-stream it forces the browser to download it instead.